# Possible to chain results in N1ql?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I'm currently trying to do a bit of complex N1QL for a project I'm working on, theoretically I could do all of this processing in multiple N1QL calls and by parsing the results each time, however if possible I'd like for this to contained in one call.

What I would like to do is:

- filter all documents that contain a "dataSync.test.id" field with more than 1 id
- Read back all other ids in that list
- Use that list to get other documents containing those ids
- Get the "dataSync.test._channels" field for those documents (optionally a filter by docType might help parsing)

This would probably return a list of "dataSync.test._channels"

Is this possible in N1QL? It appears like it might be but I can't get the syntax right.

My data structures look a little like

```
{
  "dataSync": {
    "test": {
      "_channels": [
        "RP"
      ],
      "id": [
        "dataSync_user_1015",
        "dataSync_user_1010",
        "dataSync_user_1005"
      ],
      "_lastUpdatedBy": "TEST"
    }
  },
     ...
}


{
  "dataSync": {
    "test": {
      "_channels": [
        "RSD"
      ],
      "id": [
        "dataSync_user_1010"
      ],
      "_lastUpdatedBy": "TEST"
    }
  },
...
}
```

Comment: what queries have you tried so far? I would think you'd be able to do a regular old SQL sub query to get this.

Comment: What I ended up using was a couple of queries and some java code to compliment it:

Read out ids, not including the id passed in:

select array_remove(dataSynchronization.trident.id, $dataSyncId) as idList from write where $dataSyncId in dataSynchronization.trident.id and array_length(dataSynchronization.trident.id) > 1

Then, iterate over the list of ids and query the channels object

select dataSynchronization.trident._channels from write where docType = 'user' and $dataSyncId in dataSynchronization.trident.id and array_length(dataSynchronization.trident.id) < 2";

Comment: Then update the channels

"update write set dataSynchronization.trident._channels = $channels," +
            "dataSynchronization.trident._lastUpdatedBy = $lastUpdatedBy where $dataSyncId in dataSynchronization.trident.id and array_length(dataSynchronization.trident.id) > 1"

Sorry if this is formatted badly, I didn't want to "answer" my own question

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I think you can do all these.

Initial set of IDs with filtering can be retrieved as a subquery and then you can get subsquent documents by joins.

SELECT fulldoc
FROM (select meta().id as dockey from doc where a=1) as mydoc
INNER JOIN doc fulldoc ON KEYS mydoc.dockey;

There are optimizations that can be done here.  Try the sequencing first to ensure you're get the job done.